# Is it possible to add a custom button on a toolbar of a component on AEM?

Tags: aem

[image]

On the edit mode of AEM 6.5,  if I click on a component, the toolbar above will pop up. Other than adding a dialog (spanner button) by creating cq:dialog node on CRXDE, can you create a custom button on the toolbar? If so, what are some working examples I can find online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

You will need to create a custom client library with a JS file that registers the button in the toolbar:

```
(function ($document, author) {
    var openDialog = {
        icon: 'coral-Icon--game',
        text: 'Open Dialog',
        handler: function (editable, param, target) {
            author.DialogFrame.openDialog(new author.edit.Dialog(editable));
        },
        condition: function (editable) {
            //show this action only for component type eaem-touchui-open-comp-dialog-register-action/touchui-open-component-dialog
            return editable.type === "eaem-touchui-open-comp-dialog-register-action/touchui-open-component-dialog";
        },
        isNonMulti: true
    };

    $document.on('cq-layer-activated', function (ev) {
        if (ev.layer === 'Edit') {
            author.EditorFrame.editableToolbar.registerAction('EAEM_OPEN_DIALOG', openDialog);
        }
    });
})($(document), Granite.author);
```

You can customize the icon, text, the behavior of the button and decide for which components this toolbar customization will be visible.

[source](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2017/08/aem-63-touch-ui-register-component-action-open-dialog-programatically.html)

Comment: The button is added to the last spot on the toolbar by default. Is it possible to move the button to the first spot on the left?

Comment: Yes. You can add a property `order: "before CONFIGURE",` in the action properties (next to `icon: 'coral-Icon--game'`) to decide where it will be shown. The value `CONFIGURE` is the `data-action` property of a toolbar button you want to insert your button before.